# How to buid array and display random values?

Tags: php, arrays, random

:) 
I can't write code for array. Example:

I want have page and using include import file with array. In array i want put in new line comment example:

```
id-1 = first one
id-2 = second one 
etc... 
id-333 = other comment
```

Next i want to display random value from array. Example:

```
Mr. Bad coder write comment: 
first one
```

How do this? I have read a lot of tutorials and my code looks like this:

array.php file:

```
$array_names = array(
  '1' => 'Mike',
  '2' => 'John',
  '3' => 'Ana',
);
```

File to display array:

```
<?php 
include('array.php');
echo $array_names; ?> was write a comment!
```

Comment: you want to show one name and one comment? Are they both random?

Comment: `foreach($array_names as $value){echo $value. "Was write comments <br>";}` something like that???

Answer (score 0):

If you know that each key from min to max is represented in the array, you can just select a random value like this:

```
$randomKey = mt_rand($min, $max);
echo $array_names[$randomKey]
```

If you have other types of keys in the array then the easiest way would be to create a new array with sequential keys before doing the same thing.

Comment: array_rand() is a better approach for this

Comment: Not so sure about that, read the top comments:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php